# Should this question be protected?

Tags: discussion, question-protection, new-users

This question, [How do I make a lot of money efficiently?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95854/how-do-i-make-a-lot-of-money-efficiently) has 30k views, and two great answers, but is starting to attract a lot of one-liner/short answers from new users.

There's nothing *wrong* with any of the answers themselves, most of them are actually helpful. They just all seem to boil down to *"I really like this mission/in-game mechanic, it deserves a mention"*, which could end up listing every possible way of obtaining money (if allowed to continue).

Is this grounds enough for protection? or should we encourage these types of answers instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a good candidate to me. There's a few deleted and delete-worthy there too.